# How and where CSS in XHTML file of Dynamic Web Project Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, jsf, xhtml

I'm trying to link css file to xhtml page in several ways but nothing what I did want to work. 
Here is folders structure of project:

```
Project
   Java serources
   WebContent
   **index.xhtml**
      META-INF
      WEB-INF
      style
         **style.css**
```

Now in index.xhtml file I have: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/style.css" />`

Can someone tell me what I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `resources` folder under the `WebContent`

and inside `resources` create `css` folder

then access the files like this

```
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="myNewStylesFile.css" target="head" />
```

Here's a tutorial [Resources (library) in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/resources-library-in-jsf-2-0/)

Answer (score 0):

Put your link tag as I mention below:

```
<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Comment: This in not how its being done in JSF , he better use `<h:outputStylesheet` and place the css in a proper location...